# Github Advanced Security for Azure Devops is not detecting vulnerability

Tags: azure-devops, github-advanced-security

What should I do when Github Advanced Security for Azure Devops is not a detecting vulnerability?
[image]

For example [this](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2023-36414) one is not being detected.

I'm using several packages that have a dependency on version 1.7 of azure.identity.
Microsoft.Azure.SignalR:

```
      "Microsoft.Azure.SignalR/1.18.1": {
    "dependencies": {
      "Azure.Identity": "1.7.0",
      "System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt": "6.24.0"
    }
```

Microsoft.Extensions.Azure:

```
      "Microsoft.Extensions.Azure/1.6.0": {
    "dependencies": {
      "Azure.Core": "1.25.0",
      "Azure.Identity": "1.7.0",
      "Microsoft.Extensions.Options": "7.0.0"
    }
```

Why is Github / Azure devops not seeing it?

Answer (score 2):

To test the issue, I added the same Package Reference as yours to my `.csproj` file.

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.SignalR" Version="1.18.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Azure" Version="1.6.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Run the pipeline with the `AdvancedSecurity-Dependency-Scanning@1` task.

Result:
The CVE-2023-36414 is there for `Azure.Identity 1.7.0`.
[image]

After the above, I added another Package Reference `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient 5.1.4` to my `.csproj` file. It has the dependence of `Azure.Identity (>= 1.10.3)`.

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Data.SqlClient" Version="5.1.4" />
```

Test result:

The CVE-2023-36414 is not there anymore.

[image]

We can find CVE-2023-36414 in the closed filter.

[image]

So, the Azure.Identity package version is updated by another package.

You can also check the version of Azure.Identity you have restored the package in the restore task log:

[image]

Comment: I added a new test project (xunit) in the repo and added Microsoft.Extensions.Azure 1.6.0. The vulnerability is not found. What am I doing wrong? I'm using the same yaml dependency task as your example

Comment: Hi @Enrico, are you unable to see this vulnerability (CVE-2023-36414) or all other vulnerabilities? Can you find the Azure.Identity is restored in the pipeline log? According to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/security/configure-github-advanced-security-features?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#set-up-dependency-scanning), for the most accurate scanning results, be sure to add the dependency scanning task following the build steps of a pipeline that builds the code you wish to scan.

Comment: Retried this in another repository and now it works. Strange. Could using a private nuget feed have anything to do with it?

Comment: Hi @Enrico, the private nuget feed should have no impact on GitHub Advanced Security for Azure DevOps. Could you please check again whether this repo has [Repository-level onboarding enabled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/security/configure-github-advanced-security-features?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#repository-level-onboarding)?

Comment: If you would be willing to continue troubleshooting this over chat let me know

Comment: Github Advanced Security is enabled. I can see the dashboard and the issues. Just not the one I mentioned. In my dotnet restore I also noticed the API call to 
           GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/azure.identity/1.7.0/azure.identity.1.7.0.nupkg

Comment: Hi @Enrico, I tested to use a private nuget feed in Azure Artifact and it will also find this vulnerability (CVE-2023-36414).  But to narrow down the issue, you can test to use the NuGet Gallery for this repository and see if it will work.

Comment: I'm still unable to detect the vulnarbility , even when directly including the package. How does github detect the vulnerability? Do I need to do a build/publish of my project?

Comment: I was looking into a similar issue and came across this thread on the [Microsoft Developer community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Advanced-Security-isnt-using-the-latest/10508676?sort=newest). If you see `The latest snapshot for this build and source contains the same components and source identifier (ie. commit). No components were registered` in the build log then you need to push a new commit to the branch